# How to add extensions in Mediawiki?

Tags: php, mediawiki

How do i add the below new extensions in MediaWiki?

*.xmcd and *.mcd for MathCad source files
*.m and *.dat for Matlab source files.

I have already few extensions in LocalSettings.php mentioned below

$wgFileExtensions = array_merge( $wgFileExtensions, array( 'doc','pdf', 'ppt', 'zip', 'svg', 'xls', 'vsd', 'vdx', 'docx', 'xlsx', 'pptx') );

Thanks in advance

Jayaprabu R

Comment: You mean you want to enable users to upload those files to the wiki?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, you simply add extensions as follows:

```
$wgFileExtensions = array_merge( $wgFileExtensions, array( 'doc','pdf', 'ppt', 'zip', 'svg', 'xls', 'vsd', 'vdx', 'docx', 'xlsx', 'pptx', 'xmcd' , 'mcd' , 'm' , 'dat') );
```

If this don't work, you must check your upload are enabled in same file (LocalSettings.php):

```
$wgEnableUploads = true;
```

Directory "images" must be writable. Finally, you can set the maximun size of upload:

```
$wgMaxUploadFile = '25MB';
```

Comment: After i added i am getting the below error.

The file is corrupt or has an incorrect extension. Please check the file and upload again.

Comment: This could be caused by the MIME type not matching the file extensions. If you wnat to skip this step (with any security issues that might lead to), set [`$wgVerifyMimeType=false;`}(https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgVerifyMimeType)