# How to add extensions in Mediawiki in Java?

Tags: java, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I'm working on a project which use the mediawiki API and I have to upload different types of files in my mediawiki.

By default we have the authorization for "png, gif, jpg, jpeg, webp" but I want to have pdf, docx, ppt and others.

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709263/how-to-add-extensions-in-mediawiki)  and I would like to do the same but in Java.
There is [`$wgFileExtensions`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgFileExtensions) in PHP to add extensions.

How to do this in Java ?
Thanks

Comment: Given Mediawiki is a PHP application, there is no way to do this in Java. You need to configure this in PHP/Mediawiki.

Comment: Yes, I didn't understand this. Thanks @MarkRotteveel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in Java, `$wgFileExtensions` is in the file LocalSettings.php on the server.
And you add :

```php
$wgFileExtensions = array_merge(
    $wgFileExtensions, array(
        'pdf', 'ppt' //...
        )
    );
```